# Count repetitions in multiple variables based on a set of conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have searched for an answer but have, unfortunately, been unsuccessful. I want to create a variable that identifies repetitions based on the following conditions:

1. Counter value stays the same as long as the consecutive value in A is identical to the previous row, otherwise updates
2. Counter value stays the same as long as the consecutive value in B is identical to the previous row
3. Counter value stays the same as long as the consecutive value in C is identical to the previous row
4. Counter value changes when a sequence switches from column B to C or the other way round
5. In case of overlaps (i.e., when a sequence occurs in both B and C at the same time), the sequence that had started first has the priority (e.g., rows 6 and 7 in the data frame)

Here is an example of a data set with the 'counter' variable being my desired outcome.

```
df = data.frame(A = rep(1:2, c(13,7)), 
                B = c(3,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,1), 
                C = c("b","s","f","b","s","b","b","s","s","s","f","p","s","p","f","b","s","p","f","p"), 
                counter = c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,9))
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why doesn't the counter change in row 10? `B` changes from `1` to `2`

Comment: Because 's' remains the same in column C.

Comment: Wouldn't that suggest that the counter for row 2 stay the same as well? Since `A` is `1` in row 1 and 2?

Comment: No, because columns B and C are the ones where I'm interested in repetitions. Regarding column A, it is important that repetitions in B and C happen for the same value of A. In other words, if the value of A changes, the counter changes too, regardless of the existing repetitions in B or C (e.g., row 14).

Comment: Why does `counter` change at rows 6:7? `C` stays the same but `B` changes

Comment: Because of the condition number 5 - this is an overlap so whichever sequence started sooner has the priority. In this case, that was the sequence in B which started in row 2 and finished in row 6.